# Tips to organize solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, rest, architecture

I would ask You for some tips on how would you organize work on projects with REST-api based architecture. 
Situation we actually have (simplified):

- DTO (contains DTO classes only)
- WebAPI (rest api, uses DTO)
- Client1 (ASP MVC app developed by team 1)
- Client2 (ASP MVC app developed by team 2)

The problem is that we have all of those project in one solution (both teams works on shared code and both can modify DTO/API). Now we need to split those projects to separate solutions because sometimes we need to deploy API + Client1 onto production without touching Client2.

Does someone have some experience with this kind of architecture? 
How do You cope with versioning?
Is is ok to reuse DTO class within API and clients? Maybe any good articles?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Client also uses DTO? Or just WebApi project?

Comment: @teovankot - yes, client also uses DTO.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways if to create **Nuget** package from your DTO in separate solution and organize vesioning there - package version.

Then it's better to separate your clients and add your DTO as Nuget Package. I gess it will be easier to maintain and update.

Comment: this is the one approach I was thinking about. But I wonder how to deal with situation where for example:
dev 1 - deploy package 1.5.3 with his changes
dev 2 - deploy package 1.5.4 with has changes
It is time to merge all changes made by dev1 and dev2 - how to know that everything is merged? In this example v1.5.4 don't need to have changes from 1.5.3